# TSQL insert exec(@command)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering why below statement is not working:

```
insert into #temp (ip, ping) values ('ip', exec xp_cmdshell 'ping ip')
```

I would like to get resultset where I will have ip address in one column and ping from that server. Above query returns errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Thanks in advance for explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't execute anything in a `INSERT` statement value list. You need to execute like this:

```
insert into #temp 
    execute xp_cmdshell 'ping ip'
```

[This assumes that the  `#temp` table has a column structure matching the resultset of `xp_cmdshell` ]

You can also create an intermediate temp table to contain all the columns that the stored procedure returns and then insert just the ones you want into your final table.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `insert ... exec` is notoriously inflexible.  For one thing, it won't work with a `values` clause.  Even more annoyingly, it does not support a column list.  The columns in the table have to match the output of the stored procedure exactly.

The only way to use `insert ... exec` is:

```
insert TableName exec(...)
--             ^^^--> no column list!
```

Here's an example:

```
if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#temp__%')
    drop table #temp

create table #temp (output varchar(max))
insert into #temp execute xp_cmdshell 'ping pong'
select * from #temp
```

Comment: I thought that there is any possibilyty to do that in way I mentioned. Anyway, thanks for help.